# Improving my mod_rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My application can use up to 6 query variables, to be rewritten in "clean" urls. 
So i setup the URL rewriting in the .htaccess file, which kind of works (a few edge cases probably not related to this code) but  I'm wondering: is there a more efficient way of writing it?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v2/(_admin/|_css/|_js/|phpmyadmin/|_img/) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]



# Externally redirect to add missing trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9._\-]+/)*[a-z0-9_\-]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,R,L]

# SIX PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5&title=$6&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# FIVE  PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# FOUR PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# THREE PARAMS : projects/touch/texts/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# TWO PARAMS: downloads
RewriteRule ^downloads/([^/]+)/$ index.php?section=downloads&item=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}  [NC,L]

# TWO PARAMS:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# TAG URL : index.php?tag=url+encoded+keyword
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/$ index.php?tag=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# ONE PARAM
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/$ index.php?section=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it looks fine but some improvement can be made e.g.

1. Use `QSA` (Query String Append) flag and avoid adding `%{QUERY_STRING}` all the time
2. Use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z-9_]` in regex
3. Trailing slash rule can also be simplified a lot

**Modified code:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v2/(_admin/|_css/|_js/|phpmyadmin/|_img/) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

# Externally redirect to add missing trailing slash
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# SIX PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5&title=$6&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# FIVE  PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# FOUR PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

# THREE PARAMS : projects/touch/texts/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

# TWO PARAMS: downloads
RewriteRule ^downloads/([^/]+)/$ index.php?section=downloads&item=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# TWO PARAMS:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# TAG URL : index.php?tag=url+encoded+keyword
RewriteRule ^tag/([\w-]+)/$ index.php?tag=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# ONE PARAM
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA]
```